# create -react-app is not completely working

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am trying to create a react app on windows 32 bit PC using command `create-react-app my-app` through the yarn which it creates successfully but not proceeding to display success message due to that yarn start is not working.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to hit return or another key on your keyboard? Looks like The command actually succeed to finish it's tasks. Those warnings are quite habitual with react.

Comment: Could you please specify which terminal you are using?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. For easier readability, consider posting raw text in the question, not a screenshot of the terminal only. I guess a screenshot is fine too, but text is really easier to read. Some formatting options are available through the editor.

Comment: No, I didn't hit any key from the keyboard.I was waiting for about half an hour but it was not proceeding further.

Comment: I am using windows command prompt for this.